# OCI IAM statement to allow the use of metrics from console

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

We want to restrict to only allow "Performance Hub Metrics" and "Metrics".
We have defined IAM as such so far, and this limits to Performance Hub only.  I need to know the proper operation syntax for metrics.

```
Allow group Z to inspect autonomous-database-family in compartment A

Allow group Z to use autonomous-database-family in compartment A where request.operation = 'RetrieveAutonomousDatabasePerformanceBulkData'

Allow group Z to use autonomous-database-family in compartment A where request.operation = '?? Metrics??'
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper statement to resolve this issue is as follows:

```
Allow group Z to inspect autonomous-database-family in compartment A

Allow group Z to use autonomous-database-family in compartment A where request.operation = 'RetrieveAutonomousDatabasePerformanceBulkData'

Allow group Z to use metrics  in compartment A
```